# using a 2d vector as value type in a c++ map

Tags: c++

I need to to have a map where the key is a string type and the value is a 2d vector.

I tried `map<string, vector<vector<double> > > myMap;` but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you get compiler errors, run time errors, etc?

Comment: What doesn't work? Compile error?

Comment: What doesn't work? Post some code showing the lines that are throwing the errors and the error messages themselves.

Comment: "It doesn't seem to work" tell us nothing.  What doesn't work, specifically?  Do you have a compiler error?  A runtime error?  Does it not behave as you expected?  Please be specific.

Comment: sorry, I should have asked if this was the correct syntax as I was guessing the correct syntax and got a compiler error.

Comment: @wolve80: _What_ compiler error? We are not psychics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code compiles fine for me in g++ 4.5.0:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::vector<double> > > map;
    return 0;
}
```

Perhaps you made a syntax error?